# I cannot get icons on the action bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to add an icon for **"Create Order"** to be displayed on the action bar, but the icon is not being displayed instead on the action bar only 3 dots are being showed and inside them there is written **"Create Order"**.

The following is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use app:showAsAction to ifRoom as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

**Note:**
*The app:showAsAction attribute specifies whether the action should be shown as a button on the app bar. If you set app:showAsAction="ifRoom" (as in the example code's favorite action), the action is displayed as a button if there is room in the app bar for it; if there is not enough room, excess actions are sent to the overflow menu. If you set app:showAsAction="never" (as in the example code's settings action), the action is always listed in the overflow menu, not displayed in the app bar.*

*Refer below link for more details:*
[Add Action Buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions#java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the Icon and the Text "Create Order" you can use:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

of course, it can show only, if your view has enough space for these elements.